# Listar postagem de usuário logado Python-flask

Tags: python-3.x, query, flask, sqlalchemy

Sou iniciante em flask e estou fazendo uma AppWEB onde o usuário pode se cadastrar e cadastrar e fazer postagens, é um sistema de Virtual Arline. Montei o usuário com SESSION e consigo exibir somente os dados dele. No meu banco de dados tenho a tabela usuários, onde ficam seus dados e a tabela postagens. O que quero saber agora, é como eu consigo listar no perfil do usuário, somente as postagens que ele fez, pois do jeito que fiz até agora, quando exibo as postagens aparecem as postagens de todos os usuários cadastrados. Eis o meu código e obrigado a quem ajudar.

Minha tabela onde exibo a lista de postagens

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Tripulante</th>
        <th scope="col">Voo</th>
        <th scope="col">Origem</th>
        <th scope="col">Destino</th>
        <th scope="col">Duração</th>
        <th scope="col">Aeronave</th>
        <th scope="col">Data</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for post in post %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ post.author.first_name }}</th>
        <td>{{ post.callsign_u}}</td>
        <td>{{ post.departure }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.arrival }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.flight_time }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.aircraft }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.last_seen.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

rota que lista as postagens:

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
@login_required
def user(username):
    va = db.session.query(func.sum(Post.flight_time)).first()    
    post = Post.query.order_by(Post.last_seen.desc()).all() #aqui que quero lista a postagem do usuario logado
    form1 = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()    
    return render_template('user.html', form1=form1, post=post, va=va)
```

Como eu disse, desta forma eu estou selecionando as postagens de todos os usuários e preciso de ajuda para listar as postagens somente do usuário logado no momento.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você precisa filtrar os `Post` pelos usuários que o criaram.

No `flask_login` o objeto do usuário logado pode ser acessado através de `flask.ext.login.current_user`:

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user

post = Post.query.filter(Post.user_id == current_user.id).order_by(Post.last_seen.desc()).all()
```